# Connections of SPST switch-ESE-11SV1

Tags: microcontroller, pcb-design, orcad

I am using SPST switch as a digital input to my NXP MBED Module.I have done the design of the whole circuit in OrCAD Capture and Allegro PCB Editor.
the switch I am using is Panasonic's ESE-11SV1.The land pattern in the datasheet which can also be found on the link-http://www.panasonic.com/industrial/components/pdf/011_es081_ese11_dne.pdf
shows 4 terminals-Two pins called C(common terminals) and Pin no.1 and 2.
How should all the pins be connected as digital input to the MBED Module?Usually any SPST NO (Normally Open) switch has only 2 terminals,but the Land Pattern of this part shows 4 terminals.How should they be connected?

Comment: I expect common pins will short across pins 1 and 2 when pressed but your link never mentioned C, 1 or 2 so maybe a better link?

Comment: Hi,try this link:http://industrial.panasonic.com/www-data/pdf/ATB0000/ATB0000CE4.pdf

Comment: sorry about the wrong link,you can check out the land pattern in page 6 of the new link that i just posted

Answer (score 2):

Here's the switch detail: -

[image]

You should use all four pins for mechanical rigidity and, as per the diagram both "C" pins are internally shorted on the switch and so are pins 1 and 2

Electrically you can use C and 1, or C and 2 - it doesn't matter. The switch (when closed) applies a short circuit between the left and the right pins.

I'd wire it into your MBED by having "common" down to 0V and, pin 1  to your IO pin. Your IO pin also needs a pull-up resistor to the Vcc on the MBED too. It could be between 1k and 100k.

Comment: Ok,Thanks but one more doubt.should I connect the unconnected pins to ground or should I give them No Connect when using on OrCAD Capture?

Comment: 1 and 2 can be "used" together OR you can leave 1 or 2 floating but do not connect either to ground. They are internally connected within the switch and you either use them both OR use one of them with the other open circuit

Answer (score 0):

Two of the "pins" on your switch are likely to be for the metal holder frame on the switch body to anchor it to the PC board. If you are unfamiliar with the particular switch that you hope to use then you should very well get one in hand and look it over BEFORE you commit the mounting and connections to a PC board. With the switch in hand you can easily discover which pins are hooked to the switch contact points and which ones are simply for component mounting. A multimeter is your trusted friend here.

**Now that the appropriate data sheet is provided. . .**

Use the relational diagram below (with snippets taken from the data sheet) to understand how the detector switch will connect up on your circuit board and suggested circuit connections.

[image]

Comment: Hi,I relaised that I had posted the wrong link in the question.could you check out the land pattern in page 6 of the following link:http://industrial.panasonic.com/www-data/pdf/ATB0000/ATB0000CE4.pdf   and help me with the connections.

Comment: I have updated my answer to include some information from the datasheet to help you understand the switch connections. Please note that I still recommend that it is a good idea to have one of the switch parts in hand when you do the PCB design and mechanical design of your device. The visualization this offers is extremely helpful.

Comment: Ok,but when I am doing the design on OrCAD Capture should I leave the unconnected pins to ground or should I leave them as no connect?

Comment: You can choose to leave the unconnected pins open but still in a plated through hole to provide secure mounting of the switch assembly. Alternatively you can connect both of the (C) pins to GND. You could connect the (1) pin in my diagram to the input of the MBED module in parallel with (2). You would NOT want to connect (1) to GND as that would in turn short (2) to GND through the internal connection that exists inside the switch.